# Null value sometimes returned from constant initialized in declaration. Is this a coding error?

Tags: java, static, initialization, classloader

A null value is sometimes returned by a constant that is initialized when declared. Whether or not the value is null depends on the order in which other code is executed.

I build an array that contains objects that were initialized as constants. I then print the array. Sometimes the values are all initialized correctly, sometimes not, as shown in the output below.

Correct:

```
[STRING, LOCAL_DATE_TIME, INTEGER]
```

Incorrect:

```
[STRING, null, INTEGER]
```

The different results can be had by adding or removing a line of code just before printing. The correct result is printed when the line is removed.

Here is the main class with the offending line included:

```
package foo;
import tech.tablesaw.api.DateTimeColumn;

class DummyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long missing = DateTimeColumn.MISSING_VALUE;
        new DummyPrinter().printColumnTypes();
    }
}
```

When I comment out line 1 in main, the code works as I expect.

Also, the code that implements printing must be in a separate class for the error to occur. Here's that class:

```
package foo;

import tech.tablesaw.api.ColumnType;
import java.util.Arrays;
import static tech.tablesaw.api.ColumnType.*;

class DummyPrinter {

    void printColumnTypes() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columnTypes));
    }

    private static final ColumnType[] columnTypes = {
        STRING,
        LOCAL_DATE_TIME,
        INTEGER,
    };
}
```

As you can see, the array itself is a literal constant.

The values inserted into the array are also constants. They are declared in the ColumnType interface in the line shown below:

```
DateTimeColumnType LOCAL_DATE_TIME = DateTimeColumnType.INSTANCE;
```

Source: [https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw/blob/master/core/src/main/java/tech/tablesaw/api/ColumnType.java ]

In that line, the values are provided by another constant. This one is declared in a class called DateTimeColumnType, which is a singleton.

Here is the code from that class where the Singleton is created:

```
public static final DateTimeColumnType INSTANCE =
        new DateTimeColumnType(BYTE_SIZE, "LOCAL_DATE_TIME", "DateTime");
```

Source: 
[https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw/blob/master/core/src/main/java/tech/tablesaw/columns/datetimes/DateTimeColumnType.java ]

This is again a static final (constant) variable. AFAIK, it should never return null. And the interface constant that uses it should never return null.

So, back to the line of code that turns the error on and off. As far as I can tell, the impact of this line is that it causes the class DateTimeColumnType to load in a different order when it is present than it does when it is absent.

My question is: Is there anything in the code shown that, according to the Java Language Spec, would introduce uncertainty into whether the value is initialized properly? In other words, is there a bug in my code that causes the problem? If so, what? Or is the initialization logic (while convoluted) correct from a language standpoint?

Comment: I bet you've got a circular dependency between classes, and the null occurs depending upon which point in the cycle you start from.

Comment: @AndyTurner. That does seem to be the case, but while I understood circular dependencies to be poor coding style, I was not aware that they could introduce inconsistent behavior. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, they can, in the same way that you can see uninitialized (static) final members, if you read them before they are initialized.